# Create customer for a specific store_id through soap

Tags: customer, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to create a customer through soap api v2 for magento version 1.9.3 with WS-I compliance enabled.
Using Ruby and SAVON gem.
The call i make is as follows:

```
customer_info = [
  { mode: 'customer',
    firstname: 'Name',
    lastname: 'LastName',
    store: store_id,
    store_id: store_id,
    website_id: website_id,
    group_id: group_id,
    email: 'test_magento1@mailinator.com'
  }]

customer = client.call(:customer_customer_create, message: { session_id: session_id, customerData: customer_info} )
```

everything works fine, i can create the customer in the DB, however it is not linked to the store_id that i send. it's linked to default. I send the proper store_id, website_id, group_id combination.
After this call i also do

```
shopping_cart_customer_set
```

again, with store_id, website_id and group_id. I also add store as a parameter as it seems that's how the wsdl describes it. Still no luck.

Comment: Alan Storm explains where to start debugging here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646454/soap-magento-error-on-customer-create assuming you have access to the server side? Also, check whether it wants the DB id or the store code, I always get confused.